# How can i detect opened programs in Godot3.1?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I want to detect, that is chrome opened, but I don't know, how to do that.

This is in a program, that detects how much my little brother watches YT videos.

Godot doesn't allow to get out of "user://"

Comment: Why are you using a game engine to check that chrome is running?  Wouldn't it be better to write a non-game related application for this?

Comment: They're correct that you'd probably want to go with a different approach.  Are you just wanting to know the time or something more specific?  Router logging is the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Windows 10 as operating system, you can call powershell from Godot to make it. 
In powershell, to get list of chrome process, use `get-process chrome` and you will see something like this:

```
    Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
    -------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    343      19    31404      57972       0,88   2664   2 chrome
    259      17    22972      43920       0,34   2972   2 chrome
    529      29    76956      65512       1,00   3576   2 chrome
    238      17    24148      46548       0,55   5480   2 chrome
    219      15    13084      23128       0,22   7676   2 chrome
    136      11     1992       8724       0,05   7924   2 chrome
    161       9     1676       6484       0,03  10200   2 chrome
    230      16    16504      33064       0,17  13252   2 chrome
    415      21    14372      30508       5,45  14836   2 chrome
    195    8717    44248      27944       0,75  15520   2 chrome
   1290      49    72020     129948      14,66  17652   2 chrome
```

If you write `get-process chrome | measure-object -line` you can get the number of lines:

```
    Lines Words Characters Property
    ----- ----- ---------- --------
       11
```

And, finally, if you write `get-process chrome | measure-object -line | select Lines -expandproperty Lines` you will see only the number of lines:

```
11
```

Now, apply this in Godot:

```
func _is_chrome_active() -> bool:
    var chrome_active = false
    if OS.get_name() == "Windows": # Verify that we are on Windows
        var output = []
        # Execute "get-process" in powershell and save data in "output":
        OS.execute('powershell.exe', ['/C', "get-process chrome | measure-object -line | select Lines -expandproperty Lines"], true, output)   
        var result = output[0].to_int()
        chrome_active = result > 0    # If there is more than 0 chrome processes, it will be true
        print("Number of chrome processes: " + str(result))
    return chrome_active
```

Here, it's used [`OS.execute`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_os.html) to open powershell and send the command. The result, will be saved in the `output` variable as an `Array`. Take the first (and unique) element from the and transform it in a number with the line `var result = output[0].to_int()`. After, compare the value with 0 to know if is some chrome process in execution.
This function returns true if there is some chrome process active and false if not.

Now, you can call it from a Timer and count the time elapsed with chrome opened.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect